# В чём может быть проблема? error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v120) is not installed or invalid

Tags: visual-studio-2010, настройка

Дело в том, что проект использует qt, и аналогичные ему проекты с той же версией запускаются без проблем(qt 4.8.5 судя по-всему).  Также, используется vs2010. win7 x64

Comment: Toolset v120 означает Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Хорошо. И, каким образом это можно исправить то? ИЛи почему эта ошибка выводится?

Comment: А нет, всё, нашёл в разделе "project properties". Спасибо.